# Restar horas de dos columnas datetime sql server

Tags: sql-server

estoy haciendo una query en sqlserver 2000, tengo dos columnas datetime(inicio,fin).necesito poder restar las dos columnas para saber cuantos minutos pasaron entre el inicio y el fin, algo asi como:

select fin-inicio as tiempo_espera from miTabla

ayuda por favor

Answer (score 4):

Mas claro sería algo así:

```
SELECT
    Inicio,
    Fin,
    DATEDIFF(minute, Inicio, Fin) as [MinutosTranscurridos]
FROM TuTabla
```

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar tu respuesta? De esta forma los que tengan el mismo problema pueden entender lo que describes!

Answer (score 2):

Para esto debes usar la función `DATEDIFF`:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE,Inicio,Fin)
FROM dbo.TuTabla;
```

Answer (score 0):

Dando una explicación mas amplia del problema, la solución seria utilizando como muy bien te lo ejemplifican ellos el comando **DATEDIFF**.

Dicho comando puede ser utilizado para obtener otras diferencias tales como.

-Año, Abreviatura(aa, aaaa) (Usar años de cuatro dígitos para evitar ambigüedad)

-Trimestre, Abreviatura(tt, t)

-Mes, Abreviatura(mm, m)

-Dia del año, Abreviatura(da, a)

-Día, Abreviatura(dd, d)

-Semana, Abreviatura(sm, ss)

-Hora, Abreviatura(hh)

-Minuto, Abreviatura(mi, n)

-Segundo, Abreviatura(ss, s)

-Milisegundo, Abreviatura(Ms)

La sintaxis SQL es la siguiente

```
DATEDIFF ( "Tipo" , "FECHAINI" , "FECHAFIN" )
/*Donde Tipo concierne a los tipos listados anteriormente*/
```

Las expresiones que puedem utilizarse o resolverse son:

-Fecha

-Fecha y hora

-Datetimeoffset

-Datetime2

-smalldatetime

-time

Por lo que se ejemplifica de la mejor manera como ellos lo dijeron.

```
SELECT
"FECHAINI",
"FECHAFIN",
DATEDIFF(minute, "FECHAINI", "FECHAFIN") as "MINUTOS TRANSCURRIDOS"
FROM TABLE
```

Saludos.