# Restar dos columnas y agregar resultados en otra columna

Tags: sql

Como sería la sintaxis para restar las columnas Hora_Salida - Hora_Entrada y agregar los resultados de cada fila en la columna duración? Estoy utilizando sql server 2012

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Añade por favor la estructura de tu tabla, el tipo de dato que usas para almacenar dichos valores y si has tratado algo

Comment: Seguro está pregunta te ayuda https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/13391/restar-horas-de-dos-columnas-datetime-sql-server

Comment: Utilizando la linea  select Hora_Entrada, Hora_Salida, datediff(minute, Hora_Entrada, Hora_Salida) as [Duracion] from Compras pude calcular las diferencias. Lo que me faltaría es agregar esos resultados en una columna aparte de la misma tabla. PD: Nose como agregar salto de lineas en los comentarios de Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer el `CREATE TABLE` de la siguiente forma para que te haga el cálculo automáticamente:

```
create table Compras(
  Compra  int,
  Hora_Entrada Time,
  Hora_Salida Time,
  Fecha Date,
  Dia varchar(15),
  Duracion AS datediff(minute, Hora_Entrada, Hora_Salida) PERSISTED
  );
```

Si no quieres perder los datos de la tabla, debes ejecutar los correspondientes `ALTER TABLE`:

- Quitamos la columna `Duracion`:

  `alter table Compras drop column Duracion;`
- Añadimos una columna llamada `Duracion` con el cálculo del `Datediff`:

  `alter table Compras add Duracion AS datediff(minute, Hora_Entrada, Hora_Salida) PERSISTED;`

Con ésta estructura, realizando los siguientes inserts:

```
insert into Compras (Compra, Hora_Entrada, Hora_Salida, Fecha, Dia) VALUES (1, '19:00:00', '20:31:00', '10/07/2019', 'Miércoles');
insert into Compras (Compra, Hora_Entrada, Hora_Salida, Fecha, Dia) VALUES (1, '20:00:00', '20:31:00', '10/07/2019', 'Miércoles');
insert into Compras (Compra, Hora_Entrada, Hora_Salida, Fecha, Dia) VALUES (1, '15:00:00', '18:45:00', '11/07/2019', 'Jueves');
```

Obtenemos  los siguientes resultados:

```
Compra  Hora_Entrada        Hora_Salida         Fecha       Dia         Duracion
1       19:00:00.0000000    20:31:00.0000000    2019-10-07  Miércoles   91
1       20:00:00.0000000    20:31:00.0000000    2019-10-07  Miércoles   31
1       15:00:00.0000000    18:45:00.0000000    2019-11-07  Jueves      225
```

Te dejo el [enlace del Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/99788/2) donde he hecho las pruebas.